# How to get piped Observable from Callback to execute in sync instead of async

Tags: angular

I have an Observable subscription inside my Angular Component, that uses the route resolver to return data for the view as follows:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("start");
    this._activatedRoute.data //this returns an observable after executing an http request to get the data.
        .subscribe((x) => {
            console.log("in subscribe")
            // set component variables based on returned value
        }); 

    console.log("ngOnInit complete");
});
```

What I see in console out is the following sequence (indicating to me that the observable http call is being made in sync with ngOnInit code):

```
start
in subscribe
ngOnInit complete
```

So far so good.

I now want to pipe into that observeble a second one (that executes in series), that calls out to google.maps API (which uses functions with callbacks).  I've done a LOT of looking up on how to do this.  One of the ways I'm doing it is as follows:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("start");
    this._activatedRoute.data //this returns an observable after executing an http request to get the data.
   .pipe(concatMap((data: { shopShowcase: ShopShowcase }) => this.executeGoogleAPIReturningCallbackAsObservable(data.shopShowcase))
    )
   .subscribe((x) => {
     console.log("in subscribe")
     // set component variables based on returned value
   }); 

    console.log("ngOnInit complete");
});


public executeGoogleAPIReturningCallbackAsObservable(shopShowcase: ShopShowcase): Observable<ShopShowcase> {
    console.log("in observable creation")
    //code here to define svService and svLocationRequest
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
        svService.getPanorama(svLocationRequest, (data, status) => {
        console.log("in Callback");
        let panoId = data.location.pano;
        shopShowcase.PanoId = panoId;
        observer.next(shopShowcase);
        observer.complete();
      })
    });
}
```

I have tried various approaches to creating the observable from the callback, but they all render the same console.log output sequence shown below.  Notice that this time the ngOnInit call is completing, and only THEN is the observable callback being executed.

```
start
in observable creation
ngOnInit complete
in callback
in subscribe
```

Based on much research, I'm of the understanding that .pipe(concatMap()) would cause the piped observable to be executed *in series*, thus yielding an output like so:

```
start
in observable creation
in callback
in subscribe
ngOnInit complete
```

I need the piped callback to execute in sync, because I need the component variables to be set by the time `ngOnInitComplete` is reached.

Please advise how I can my approach to do so?

Comment: The question would be, why do you need it to be complete in the ngOninit? You can do the work you need inside the subscribe right?

Comment: As far as I know, Angular life cycle hooks cannot be async (you can still force them to be async but the hooks won't execute in the right order anymore). So trying to delay a hook to wait for a async task to complete (I assume your `svService.getPanorama` is async?) is pretty much impossible. I would suggest moving all the async codes to the `resolver`

Comment: I'm exploring the move to put the additional call into .subscribe. But am I misunderstanding the *serial* nature of concatMap here?

Comment: The serial nature of concatMap refers to the observables, not the subscribe. The subscribe is never guaranteed to be synchronous. Since you are doing an asynchronous operation (HTTP call) in your observable stream, it is guaranteed to be asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks pascalpuetz.  Please see my 1st comment to Romario Putra's answer though?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood how Observable works (I don't mean in an offensive way). Observable is just like async await/promise but for multiple values. Your "non-expected" output is correct.

> start
> in observable creation
> ngOnInit complete
> in callback
> in subscribe

Above output is correct because of how Observable works, async. If you want to do something after observable subscribe, you can use tap() operator or just put the logic in subscribe(), and you could throw next/complete (subscribe({next: x, complete: x)

Comment: Thanks for this.  But if you think about the scenario, even without the .pipe(concatMap) of an additional observable, even the original observable which retrieves the original data is also an http post, which is also an async operation.  Yet it returns synchronously?  And its from this point of view that I am wondering, what makes my piped observable any different?

Comment: Could it have to do with the way ActivatedRoute resolver works?